# How to launch DatePickerPage from ApplicationBarIconButton?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, datepicker

I've tried to launch `DatePickerPage` after `ApplicationBarIconButton` is tapped.

I had hope that it would be easy as follows:

```
    DatePickerPage dpp = new DatePickerPage();

    dpp.Show();

    ((ApplicationBarIconButton)ApplicationBar.Buttons[0]).Text = dpp.Value.ToString();
```

...but it wouldn't.

Could you give me some suggestions, please?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think the `DatePickerPage` is really intended to be used directly. The key control here is the `DatePicker`, which itself handles showing the picker page. For detailed information about using the `DatePicker` control, check out [this article](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/wp7-datepicker-and-timepicker-in-depth--api-and-customization) on WindowsPhoneGeek.com.

Given that the label of appbar icon buttons is not visible by default, it seems a bit strange to update the label in this way. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I was afraid it would be so. I've already read that article on WindowsPhoneGeek.com. Code written in my question is just an example which I wanted to show what kind of problem that was. I want to use DatePicker in ApplicationBar because in my apps design all actions can be reached from ApplicationBar. I've tried to avoid situation when I have to put a button in content panel.

Comment: @Maku Did you achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Maku, I'm letting users activate a datepicker from the ApplicationBar by placing it in the page and setting Height/Width to zero and then focusing the DatePicker when the ApplicationBarIcon is pressed.

Comment: I've done as you posted. 
`<toolkit:DatePicker Width="0" Height="0" x:Name="TestDP"/>`
and code behind 
`private void ApplicationBarIconButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TestDP.Focus();                             
        }`
But it is not working for me. Could you be more specific in your solution. Thank you!